# Google Play Console - How do I resubmit an app release that's been rejected?

Tags: google-play-console

My app release was rejected due to the description. I edited the description to be more verbose, and saved the changes.

However, I can not find out where to "resubmit" this rejected release.

Where would I do that? I don't want to create a new release, if all I have to do is change the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fixing the issue for my release (missing description), I actually had to go to "Publishing Overview" and from there was able to find the button "Send for review" to submit the newest release.